# How to perform pattern matching search in AWS Cloud Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, pattern-matching, cloud, amazon-cloudsearch

Suppose I have three document having data 
1. LSU
2. LSUSDC
3. ALSU
Now If I want to perform search for "LSU", it should return all three documents.
I want to create structured type(not simple) aws cloudsearch query for this.

Comment: What about `field_name LIKE '%LSU%'`? See the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_patternmatching_condition_like.html). Or if you need to match `LSU` at the start or end, `field_name LIKE 'LSU%' or field_name LIKE '%LSU'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your reply, but it does not work as mysql query, If you look for queries in aws cloud search, it will be different, we can not use "LIKE" in it

Answer (score 0):

One solution which I found is to use "prefix" with structured query
like

```
(and (prefix field=field_name 'lsu'))
```

If using simple query then simply use `'lsu*'`
But this does not provide ALSU in result.

we cannot use `'*lsu'`. and there is nothing like suffix.

Comment: Can you please share the relevant documentation link?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure please look into this [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html]

Comment: Ok, what about `(and field=field_name 'lsu*' (or field=field_name '*lsu'))`?  I am not sure about the exact syntax, but `*` is mentioned as a supported wildcard.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes it is supported wild card but it wont work in case of `(and field=field_name '*lsu')` . It is only supporting in `(and field=field_name 'lsu*')`.